# Add web link in jira issue

Tags: python, hyperlink, jira

I want to know web link in jira issue, in the same section of jira issue.
I try this , but I get an error

```
jira.add_simple_link(issue_edit, {
        "object": {
            "url":"http://www.mycompany.com/support?id=1",
            "title":"Crazy customer support issue"
        }
    })

jira.utils.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400
    text: 'URL' is required., 'Link Text' is required
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try removing the `object` wrapper like this...

```
jira.add_simple_link(issue_edit,  {
        "url":"http://www.mycompany.com/support?id=1",
        "title":"Crazy customer support issue"
    }
)
```